# Master Data Services Data import syserr 207

Tags: sql-server, ssis, master-data-services, master-data-management

I have built a relatively simple data model and I am trying to import data into it for the first time using SSIS. I fallowed this tutorial http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/2/16/importing-data-into-master-data-services-2012-part-1.html but after a load my staging table my publish step fails giving this error

syserr207|invalid column name uda_6_103

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @RC int 
DECLARE @VersionName nvarchar(50)..." failed with the following error: "SYSERR207|Invalid column name 'uda_6_103'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

My query is

```
DECLARE @RC int 
DECLARE @VersionName nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @LogFlag int 
DECLARE @BatchTag nvarchar(50)

SET @VersionName = N'VERSION_1' 
SET @LogFlag = 1 
SET @BatchTag = ?

EXECUTE @RC =[stg].[udp_MMG_Budget_Update_Leaf]
   @VersionName 
  ,@LogFlag 
  ,@BatchTag 
GO
```

I am running MDS on sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting a similar error when trying to publish data in an entity that had **change tracking enabled** on the Code column.

You can track down the column causing this issue by running this query against your Master Data Services database.

```
SELECT ID, TableColumn FROM mdm.tblAttribute WHERE ChangeTrackingGroup > 0 AND MemberType_ID = 1
```

To fix this issue, on the Master Data Services administration site, go to System Administration -> Model -> Entities and edit the column causing the issue and uncheck the checkbox for change tracking . I'm not sure why change tracking is not supported in certain cases, but it seems like a bug.